# Problems running dll

Tags: c#, c++-cli

There are no errors when building **dll** but it does not work.

A button should appear in the program when clicked, the message "TEST" would appear.
But the button just does not appear despite of not emitting any while building.

The exact same code in C# works but is needed in cli.

My DllExport:

```
#pragma region Usings
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;


#pragma endregion

namespace RGiesecke
{
    namespace DllExport
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to control how to create an unmanaged export for a static method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// You are not bound to using this class in this assembly.
        /// By default, any attribute named "RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportAttribute.DllExportAttribute" will do the trick.
        /// Even if it is declared to be only visible inside the assembly with the static methods you want to export.
        /// In such a case the naming and typing of the fileds/properties is critical or otherwise the provided values will not be used.
        /// </remarks>
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets::Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
        private ref class DllExportAttribute : Attribute
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
        public:
            DllExportAttribute()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="exportName">Name of the unmanaged export.
            /// <seealso cref="ExportName"/></param>
            DllExportAttribute(String ^exportName) //: DllExportAttribute(exportName, System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention::StdCall)


            {


            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="exportName">Name of the unmanaged export.
            /// <seealso cref="ExportName"/></param>
            /// <param name="callingConvention">The calling convention of the unmanaged .
            /// <seealso cref="CallingConvention"/></param>
            DllExportAttribute(String ^exportName,  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention callingConvention)
            {

                ExportName = exportName;
                CallingConvention = callingConvention;
            }

        private:
            static  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention CConv = safe_cast< System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention>(0);


            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the calling convention that will be used by the unmanaged export.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The calling convention.</value>
        public:
            property  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention CallingConvention
            {
                 System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention get()
                {
                    return CConv;
                }
                void set( System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention value)
                {
                    CConv = value;
                }
            }

        private:
            String ^ExpName;

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the unmanaged export.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The name of the export.</value>
        public:
            property String ^ExportName
            {
                String ^get()
                {
                    return ExpName;
                }
                void set(String ^value)
                {
                    ExpName = value;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My Class:

```
// ISHDAN.h

#pragma once
#include "DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportAttribute.h"

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace RGiesecke::DllExport;
namespace Class2 {

    public ref class Class1
    {

        [DllExport("ISHDAN", CallingConvention = System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
        double static ISHDAN(String ^connTemp, String ^connEoi, String ^cex, String ^SV, String ^SO, String ^izd, String ^TP, String ^cher)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("TEST");
          return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Please can you look at the code, and give me some clues?

Comment: _A button should appear_ - what button? I don't see any in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got C++ and C++/CLI concepts confused, and merging them makes neither one work.

- In C++/CLI, you don't have to tag anything as DllExport. Make the class public and compile it. In C#, add it as a reference in the same way as you would a C# DLL.
- I'm not sure why you're creating your own DllExportAttribute. If you make your own, the .Net compiler won't do anything with it.

Here's all you need to do:

- Delete your class DllExportAttribute.
- Just define your C++/CLI class as a public class with a public method.

  ```
  namespace Class2
  {
      public ref class Class1
      {
      public:
          double static ISHDAN(String ^connTemp, String ^connEoi, String ^cex, String ^SV, String ^SO, String ^izd, String ^TP, String ^cher)
          {
              MessageBox::Show("TEST");
              return 1;
          }
      };
  }
  ```
- Call this like a normal method from C#.

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Class2.Class1.ISHDAN("temp", "eoi", "cex", "sv", "so", "izd", "tp", "cher");
  }
  ```

Comment: A friend needs all the code to work on c ++ / cli. Try to explain in detail if I can be a non-wholesale programmer, I am an intern.

Comment: and I cannot enter the project code to which the dll is connected, I have to drop the dll into the root folder and the point is that the same dll only on c # just needs to be on c ++ / cli